# Exchange Partition giving -Table or index is not partitioned. Invalid syntax

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, partitioning, partition

I have 2 schemas TBCAM and AR_TBCAM. There is a table called BKP_COST_EVENT in TBCAM which I have partitioned and I have moved the partition data into another simple table in AR_TBCAM schema called BKP_COST_EVENT_P2016. Now the data has moved to AR_TBCAM schema via this query

```
ALTER TABLE BKP_COST_EVENT EXCHANGE PARTITION P2016 WITH TABLE AR_TBCAM.BKP_COST_EVENT_P2016 INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION;
```

Now I want to bring the partition data back into the original table BKP_COST_EVENT.
But when I run this query standing on AR_TBCAM

```
ALTER TABLE BKP_COST_EVENT_P2016 EXCHANGE PARTITION P2016 WITH TABLE TBCAM.BKP_COST_EVENT INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION;
```

It is giving this error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
ALTER TABLE BKP_COST_EVENT_P2016 EXCHANGE PARTITION P2016 WITH TABLE TBCAM.BKP_COST_EVENT INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION
Error report -
ORA-14501: object is not partitioned
14501. 00000 -  "object is not partitioned"
*Cause:    Table or index is not partitioned.  Invalid syntax.
*Action:   Retry the command with correct syntax.
```

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong? Or how to bring/restore the data back to my TBCAM schema table BKP_COST_EVENT. 
I have not dropped the partition p2016 in the original BKP_COST_EVENT

Comment: What user were you logged in as when executing each statement?

Comment: The last command which failed ..logged as AR_TBCAM

Comment: How many partitions are there on AR_TBCAM.BKP_COST_EVENT_P2016 and TBCAM.BKP_COST_EVENT. And do either of these have any non-LOCAL indexes?

Comment: There are no partitions in AR_TBCAM schema table but there are 4 partitions  in TBCAM schema table..I just exchanged one partition into the AR_TBCAM schema table

Comment: There are no non-local index in either table

Comment: If I understand you correctly, there are currently no partitions on AR_TBCAM.BKP_COST_EVENT_P2016. If that's the case, then obviously you can't exchange a partition on AR_TBCAM.BKP_COST_EVENT_P2016 with a similar partition on TBCAM.BKP_COST_EVENT because there are no partitions on the AR_TBCAM table. ???

Comment: Then what is the best way to move data from unpartioned table back to the partitioned one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In exchange partition syntax first table should be the one which is partitioned, second should be unpartitioned one.
So, your first command was correct but 2nd command is wrong.
If you are bringing back data to same table's partition run the same command again.

ALTER TABLE BKP_COST_EVENT EXCHANGE PARTITION P2016 WITH TABLE AR_TBCAM.BKP_COST_EVENT_P2016 INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION;

Also, if there are no indexes to be moved, its better not to use including indexes clause.

Comment: How will the same command, which has moved the data from partitioned to unpartitioned table will bring back the data from unpartitioned to partitioned table..I am lil confused.

Comment: Partition exchange does not actually move data but renames the segment. When you perform partition exchange between partition p1 of table t1 and table t2, t2 segment is renamed to t1-p1 and t1-p1 is renamed to t2. And that is the reason partition exchange is so fast.

Comment: so my goal was to reduce the size of t1..by partition exchange to t2 table in diff schema and diff tablespace....so you mean to say the size of t1 remains the same even after exchange with t2 which resides in diff schema and diff tablespace

Comment: overall size in DB remains same.. table size may change.. Suppose you have 3 partitions in t1 with different size. t1-p1(100 mb), t1-p2(200 mb), t1-p3(400 mb). and you have t2 of size 25mb. after partition exchange of t1-p1 with t2, t1 will still have 3 partitions, but with size 25mb, 200mb and 400mb, whereas t2 will now be of size 100mb. Because its just renaming segment. if  you want to keep the data in same table and reduce the size you should perform compression on table; or partition.

Comment: But actually what I did was INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE some condition,,and inserted some data into the partition of t1 from t2..now when I try to run the Alter exchange partition command again..I am getting ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION ...So I shoudnt have done that..its either all or none restoration

Comment: Even after deleting the data in the t1 table..I am not able to run the alter exchange command-giving the same error. ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION
14097. 00000 -  "column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION"
*Cause:    The corresponding columns in the tables specified in the
           ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION are of different type or size
*Action:   Ensure that the two tables have the same number of columns

Comment: Can you generate the DDL of the two tables and put here. It clearly says column mismatch

Comment: I have raised a new question for this problem..Here is the link -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61720937/alter-table-exchange-partition-giving-error