# Alter Table Exchange Partition giving error

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, partitioning, partition

I am trying to bring the partitioned data back into the original table. 
But getting the following error.
I swapped the partitioned data into AR_TBCAM.BKP_COST_EVENT_P2016 table via this command

```
ALTER TABLE BKP_COST_EVENT EXCHANGE PARTITION P2016 WITH TABLE AR_TBCAM.BKP_COST_EVENT_P2016 INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION;
```

But I want to bring the data back into the TBCAM.BKP_COST_EVENT table.

Meanwhile I have split the p2016 into 3 partitions -p2014,p2015,p2016 based on year.

As per suggestion, I am issuing the same command to bring back the data into the partitioned table.
But getting the following error:

```
ALTER TABLE BKP_COST_EVENT EXCHANGE PARTITION P2016 WITH TABLE AR_TBCAM.BKP_COST_EVENT_P2016 INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION
Error report -
ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION
14097. 00000 -  "column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION"
*Cause:    The corresponding columns in the tables specified in the
           ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION are of different type or size
*Action:   Ensure that the two tables have the same number of columns
           with the same type and size.
```

DDL for partitioned table:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  File created - Monday-May-11-2020   
--------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table BKP_COST_EVENT
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT" 
   (    "MDL_VER_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EVENT_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EVENT_TYP_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "TRIGGER_TYP_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EVENT_START_DT" DATE, 
    "EVENT_END_DT" DATE, 
    "EVENT_DURATION_DAYS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EVENT_DESC" VARCHAR2(300 BYTE), 
    "EQUIP_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "SITE_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EQUIP_CUM_ACT_HRS" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "EQUIP_CUM_ACT_STARTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EQUIP_CUM_FFHRS" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "EQUIP_CUM_FFSTARTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EQUIP_CUM_CI_FFHRS" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "EQUIP_CUM_CI_FFSTARTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "PROJ_PART_PURCHASE_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "PROJ_PART_PURCHASE_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "PROJ_PART_REPAIR_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "PROJ_PART_REPAIR_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "PROJ_SERV_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "PROJ_SERV_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "PROJ_FALLOUT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "PROJ_FALLOUT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_PART_PURCHASE_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_PART_PURCHASE_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_REPAIR_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_REPAIR_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_SERV_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_SERV_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_FALLOUT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_FALLOUT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "MANUAL_EVENT_IND" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "RECONFIG_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "ACTUALIZE_IND" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "COSMOS_EVENT_ID" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "CREATED_BY" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "CREATED_DT" DATE, 
    "UPDATED_DT" DATE, 
    "UPDATED_BY" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "DELIMIT_PART_KIT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "COMMENTS" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "REASON_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "MANUAL_CBM_IND" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "PERSISTENT_ID" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "ORIGINAL_EVENT_TYP_ID" NUMBER, 
    "EOT_CAUSED_BY" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "EOT_EVENT_TYP_ID" NUMBER, 
    "INSPECTION_FLAG" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "OFS_ID" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "OFS_STATUS" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "EQUIP_EVE_INV_ACT_HRS" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "EQUIP_EVE_INV_ACT_STARTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EQUIP_EVE_INV_FFHRS" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "EQUIP_EVE_INV_FFSTARTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EQUIP_SEC_INV_ACT_HRS" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "EQUIP_SEC_INV_ACT_STARTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EQUIP_SEC_INV_FFHRS" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "EQUIP_SEC_INV_FFSTARTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "NON_MAINT_FLAG" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "UNSCHD_MANEVT_FLAG" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "VARIANCE_CAT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "VARIANCE_SUBCAT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "VARIANCE_COMMENT" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "FUTURE_MOB_TYP" NUMBER, 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_PART_PURCHSE_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_PART_PURCHSE_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_PART_REPAIR_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_PART_REPAIR_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_SERV_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_SERV_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_FALLOUT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_FALLOUT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_PART_PURCHSE_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_PART_PURCHSE_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_PART_PURCHSE_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_PART_PURCHSE_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_REPAIR_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_REPAIR_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_REPAIR_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_REPAIR_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_SERV_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_SERV_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_SERV_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_SERV_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_FALLOUT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_FALLOUT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_FALLOUT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_FALLOUT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_INSPECT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_INSPECT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_INSPECT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_INSPECT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_INSPECT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_INSPECT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_OUTSTAND_INSPECT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_OUTSTAND_INSPECT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_OUTSTAND_INSPECT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWORK_OUTSTAND_INSPECT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "BUSINESS_GRP_EVENT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "FUTURE_MOB_EVENT" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "OFS_EVENT_DT" DATE, 
    "OFS_EVENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "EVENTHOURS" NUMBER(*,0)
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CAMSDATA" 
  PARTITION BY RANGE ("CREATED_DT") 
 (PARTITION "P13"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2014-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "AR_TBCAM_TABLES" , 
 PARTITION "P14"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "AR_TBCAM_TABLES" , 
 PARTITION "P2016"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2016-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "AR_TBCAM_TABLES" , 
 PARTITION "P2017"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CAMSDATA" , 
 PARTITION "P2018"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CAMSDATA" , 
 PARTITION "P2019"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2019-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CAMSDATA" , 
 PARTITION "P"  VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CAMSDATA" ) ;

   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."MDL_VER_ID" IS 'This column holds the unique identifier for the model version';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."EVENT_ID" IS 'Unique Id for the event (Sequential number)';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."EVENT_TYP_ID" IS 'This is a unique identifier for an event type. It is a running serial number.

From Event type master table';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."TRIGGER_TYP_ID" IS 'Unique id for a trigger type';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."EVENT_START_DT" IS 'Start date for the event, as computed by the system during simulation.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."EVENT_END_DT" IS 'End date of the event as computed by the system during simulation';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."EVENT_DURATION_DAYS" IS 'Duration (in days) of the event';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."EVENT_DESC" IS 'Event description (displayed on UI)';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."EQUIP_ID" IS 'Unique Identifier for Equipment.
LMS_CONTRACT_VERSION_UNIT.ID_UNIT

For site level events,this will be null';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."SITE_ID" IS 'Unique id for a site. LMS_CONTRACT_VERSION_SITE.    ID_SITE

';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."EQUIP_CUM_ACT_HRS" IS 'Actual Hours when this event will occur.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."EQUIP_CUM_ACT_STARTS" IS 'Actual Starts when this event will occur';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."EQUIP_CUM_FFHRS" IS 'Actual FFHours when this event will occur';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."EQUIP_CUM_FFSTARTS" IS 'Actual FFStarts when this event will occur';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."PROJ_PART_PURCHASE_COST" IS 'Total Purchase cost of all parts coming in during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."PROJ_PART_PURCHASE_PRICE" IS 'Total Purchase price of all parts coming in during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."PROJ_PART_REPAIR_COST" IS 'Total Repair cost of all parts going out during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."PROJ_PART_REPAIR_PRICE" IS 'Total Repair price of all parts going out during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."PROJ_SERV_COST" IS 'Total cost of all services items that occur during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."PROJ_SERV_PRICE" IS 'Total price of all services items that occur during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."PROJ_FALLOUT_PRICE" IS 'Total Fallout price of all parts going out during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."PROJ_FALLOUT_COST" IS 'Total Fallout cost of all parts going out during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."ACT_PART_PURCHASE_COST" IS 'Actual Purchase cost of all parts coming in during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."ACT_PART_PURCHASE_PRICE" IS 'Actual Purchase price of all parts coming in during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."ACT_REPAIR_COST" IS 'Actual repair cost of all parts going out during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."ACT_REPAIR_PRICE" IS 'Actual repair price of all parts going out during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."ACT_SERV_COST" IS 'Actual service cost of all parts going out during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."ACT_SERV_PRICE" IS 'Actual service price of all parts going out during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."ACT_FALLOUT_PRICE" IS 'Actual Fallout price of all parts going out during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."ACT_FALLOUT_COST" IS 'Actual Fallout cost of all parts going out during this event.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."MANUAL_EVENT_IND" IS 'This field stores yes (Y) and no (N) value for manually added event and system generated event respectively.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."RECONFIG_ID" IS 'Unique id for a reconfiguration (sequential number)';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."ACTUALIZE_IND" IS 'This field stores the indicator whether the event actually happened (';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."COSMOS_EVENT_ID" IS 'This is Unique Identifier to identify the Cosmos event ';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."CREATED_BY" IS 'The user who created the record';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."CREATED_DT" IS 'Date when the record was created';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."UPDATED_DT" IS 'LMS_CATALOG_VERSION.DT_UPDATE_DATETIME
';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."UPDATED_BY" IS 'LMS_CATALOG_VERSION.ID_UPDATE_USER
';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT"."EVENTHOURS" IS 'This column holds the hours at which the event occured';
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index COSPK_EVENT_EVENT_TYP_ID
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "TBCAM"."COSPK_EVENT_EVENT_TYP_ID" ON "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT" ("MDL_VER_ID", "EVENT_ID") 
  PCTFREE 20 INITRANS 5 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 131072 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CAMSINDEX" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index COSFK_EVENT_EVENT_TYP_ID
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE INDEX "TBCAM"."COSFK_EVENT_EVENT_TYP_ID" ON "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT" ("EVENT_TYP_ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 5 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 131072 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CAMSINDEX" ;
  ALTER INDEX "TBCAM"."COSFK_EVENT_EVENT_TYP_ID"  UNUSABLE;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table BKP_COST_EVENT
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "COSPK_EVENT_EVENT_TYP_ID_PR" PRIMARY KEY ("MDL_VER_ID", "EVENT_ID") DISABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT" ADD SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA (ALL) COLUMNS;
  ALTER TABLE "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT" MODIFY ("MDL_VER_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT" MODIFY ("EVENT_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT" MODIFY ("EVENT_TYP_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT" MODIFY ("ACTUALIZE_IND" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT" MODIFY ("CREATED_BY" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT" MODIFY ("CREATED_DT" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT" MODIFY ("UPDATED_DT" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT" MODIFY ("UPDATED_BY" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

DDL for Non-Partitioned Table:

```
  CREATE TABLE "AR_TBCAM"."BKP_COST_EVENT_P2016" 
   (    "MDL_VER_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EVENT_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EVENT_TYP_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "TRIGGER_TYP_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EVENT_START_DT" DATE, 
    "EVENT_END_DT" DATE, 
    "EVENT_DURATION_DAYS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EVENT_DESC" VARCHAR2(300 BYTE), 
    "EQUIP_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "SITE_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EQUIP_CUM_ACT_HRS" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "EQUIP_CUM_ACT_STARTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EQUIP_CUM_FFHRS" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "EQUIP_CUM_FFSTARTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EQUIP_CUM_CI_FFHRS" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "EQUIP_CUM_CI_FFSTARTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "PROJ_PART_PURCHASE_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "PROJ_PART_PURCHASE_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "PROJ_PART_REPAIR_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "PROJ_PART_REPAIR_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "PROJ_SERV_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "PROJ_SERV_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "PROJ_FALLOUT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "PROJ_FALLOUT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_PART_PURCHASE_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_PART_PURCHASE_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_REPAIR_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_REPAIR_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_SERV_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_SERV_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_FALLOUT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "ACT_FALLOUT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "MANUAL_EVENT_IND" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "RECONFIG_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "ACTUALIZE_IND" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "COSMOS_EVENT_ID" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "CREATED_BY" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "CREATED_DT" DATE, 
    "UPDATED_DT" DATE, 
    "UPDATED_BY" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "DELIMIT_PART_KIT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "COMMENTS" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "REASON_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "MANUAL_CBM_IND" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "PERSISTENT_ID" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "ORIGINAL_EVENT_TYP_ID" NUMBER, 
    "EOT_CAUSED_BY" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "EOT_EVENT_TYP_ID" NUMBER, 
    "INSPECTION_FLAG" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "OFS_ID" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "OFS_STATUS" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "EQUIP_EVE_INV_ACT_HRS" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "EQUIP_EVE_INV_ACT_STARTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EQUIP_EVE_INV_FFHRS" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "EQUIP_EVE_INV_FFSTARTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EQUIP_SEC_INV_ACT_HRS" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "EQUIP_SEC_INV_ACT_STARTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "EQUIP_SEC_INV_FFHRS" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "EQUIP_SEC_INV_FFSTARTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "NON_MAINT_FLAG" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "UNSCHD_MANEVT_FLAG" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "VARIANCE_CAT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "VARIANCE_SUBCAT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "VARIANCE_COMMENT" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "FUTURE_MOB_TYP" NUMBER, 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_PART_PURCHSE_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_PART_PURCHSE_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_PART_REPAIR_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_PART_REPAIR_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_SERV_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_SERV_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_FALLOUT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_FALLOUT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_PART_PURCHSE_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_PART_PURCHSE_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_PART_PURCHSE_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_PART_PURCHSE_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_REPAIR_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_REPAIR_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_REPAIR_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_REPAIR_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_SERV_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_SERV_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_SERV_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_SERV_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_FALLOUT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_FALLOUT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_FALLOUT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_FALLOUT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_INSPECT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_PROJ_INSPECT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_INSPECT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_INSPECT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_ACT_INSPECT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_ACT_INSPECT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_OUTSTAND_INSPECT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWRK_OUTSTAND_INSPECT_PRICE" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "UNPLAN_OUTSTAND_INSPECT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "XTRAWORK_OUTSTAND_INSPECT_COST" NUMBER(14,2), 
    "BUSINESS_GRP_EVENT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "FUTURE_MOB_EVENT" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "OFS_EVENT_DT" DATE, 
    "OFS_EVENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "EVENTHOURS" NUMBER(*,0)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CAMSDATA" ;
```

Comment: Columns match based on the DDL you have provided. can you post data from all_tab_cols ?? for these 2 tables..?

Comment: or you can yourself full outer join first table data from all_tab_cols with second table's data from all_tab_cols and compare what's different.. Generally the differences are in column order, size or even unused columns

Comment: Can you please, please provide in future a minimal example? Are we supposed to ogle over 104 columns to spot any differences? Just create a copy of your tables with a handful of columns, and reproduce the error. Quite likely you'll find the error already while doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the column order and datatypes of the exchangees. I'd use the data dictionary views `ALL_TAB_COLS` as it's most reliable. For instance, for the example tables

```
CREATE TABLE t(a NUMBER, b NUMBER, c CHAR, d DATE)
 PARTITION BY RANGE (d) (PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (DATE '2014-01-01'));

CREATE TABLE p(a NUMBER, b NUMBER, d DATE, c CHAR);

ALTER TABLE t EXCHANGE PARTITION p1 WITH TABLE p;
ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION
```

you'll find the following differences (I used `USER_TAB_COLS` for simplification):

```
WITH 
  t AS (SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'T'),
  p AS (SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'P')
SELECT internal_column_id, t.column_name, t.data_type, p.column_name, p.data_type
  FROM t FULL OUTER JOIN p USING (internal_column_id);

1 A NUMBER A NUMBER
2 B NUMBER B NUMBER
3 C CHAR   D DATE    <= different column order 
4 D DATE   C CHAR    <=
```

But the differences could be more subtle, like the differences in the datatype:

```
CREATE TABLE q(a NUMBER, b NUMBER, d DATE, c VARCHAR2(1));
ALTER TABLE t EXCHANGE PARTITION p1 WITH TABLE q;

1 A NUMBER A NUMBER
2 B NUMBER B NUMBER
3 C CHAR   C VARCHAR2 <= different data type
4 D DATE   C DATE
```

It is important to use `DBA/ALL/USER_TAB_COLS` and not `DBA/ALL/USER_TAB_COLLUMNS`, as it shows all the hidden columns.

EDIT: A more complete query would look like

```
WITH 
  t AS (SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'T'),
  p AS (SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'P')
SELECT column_id, 
       t.column_name, t.data_type, t.data_length,
       p.column_name, p.data_type, p.data_length
  FROM t FULL OUTER JOIN p USING (column_id)
 WHERE t.column_name IS NULL          -- column missing
    OR p.column_name IS NULL          -- column missing
    OR t.column_name <> p.column_name -- column name different
    OR t.data_type   <> p.data_type   -- datatype different
    OR t.data_length <> p.data_length -- data size different;
```

EDIT:

Unused columns (which are displayed in `DBA/ALL/USER_UNUSED_COL_TABS`) will also prevent a partition exchange:

```
CREATE TABLE p(a NUMBER, b NUMBER, c CHAR, d DATE, e NUMBER);
ALTER TABLE p SET UNUSED (e);
ALTER TABLE t EXCHANGE PARTITION p1 WITH TABLE p;
ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION

ALTER TABLE p DROP UNUSED COLUMNS;
ALTER TABLE t EXCHANGE PARTITION p1 WITH TABLE p;
Table T altered.
```

Comment: With the above query, there is no difference found..it still shows 104 columns..no hidden columns or anything

Comment: Thanks for running the query. If column names and datatypes are identical, you'll need to compare the column sizes. Just include t.data_length into the query

Comment: even the data_length matches :(

Comment: Maybe it's unused columns?

Comment: ALL IN on unused columns :)

Comment: @ThomasG, what do you mean with "ALL IN"?

Comment: @wolφi you obviously don't play poker... It means that I bet all I have on an unused column issue. There should be a column hidden somewhere and he should find it on DBA_UNUSED_COL_TABS table. +1

Comment: There is diff in NUM_DISTINCT, HIGH_VALUE,LOW_VALUE,DENSITY,NUM_NULLS..etc..do they all have to match for the alter exchange to work

Comment: The structure of the data needs to be the same, but the data can and will be different. The columns you mentioned don't need to be the same. What do the unused columns say?

Comment: I ran SELECT * FROM USER_UNUSED_COL_TABS where table_name = 'BKP_COST_EVENT' for both the tables - its resulted nothing :(

Comment: Just saw that your two tables are in different schemas. To be safe, please doublecheck with `SELECT * FROM all_unused_col_tabs WHERE table_name IN ('BKP_COST_EVENT','BKP_COST_EVENT_P2016');`

Comment: The issue is resolved, once I added the Primary key constraints and all other constraints  similar to the partitioned table to the storage table..I was able to exchange Partition :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to Exchange partition once I put all the constraints to the storage table similar to the partitioned table.